# Как разделить List во View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, chart.js

Использую ChartJS для отрисовки диаграммы. В принимаемых значениях lables и data может обрабатываться только разделенные значения. Но в моем случае текст идет монолитно.

View

```
<script>
    function chart1() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
        window.myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: [@foreach (var m in Model) { @m.NameArea}],
                datasets: [{
                        label: 'Районы',
                    data: [@foreach (var m in Model) { @m.AreaParameter}],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    };</script>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string connString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\database.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            List<Area> currentArea = new List<Area>();
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT NameArea, AreaParameter FROM FileTable", conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    List<Area> dictList = new List<Area>();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        currentArea.Add(new Area()
                        {
                            //Id = Int32.Parse(reader["id"].ToString()),
                            NameArea = reader["NameArea"].ToString(),
                            AreaParameter = Int32.Parse(reader["AreaParameter"].ToString())
                        });
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand comDelete = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM FileTable", conn);
            comDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            return View(currentArea);
        }
    }
```

В итоге скрипт получает список

```
labels: [ОдинДваТриЧетыре]
```

А хотелось бы увидеть

```
labels: ['Один', 'Два', 'Три', 'Четыре']
```

Comment: Быть может `return Json(currentArea);`?

Comment: Пока еще не особо общался с Json, но если альтернативного решения не найдется, то видимо придется.

Comment: Так что оно отдает по факту в JSON? Вообще это [нативный формат](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) для данных в JS.

Comment: НУ весь объект отдает в формат Json. С которым мне еще предстоит разбираться.

Answer (score 0):

В общем смог решить, но с костылем

```
....
labels: [@foreach (var m in Model) {@Html.Raw("'"+String.Join("', '", m.NameArea)+"', ")}]
....
```

Осталась проблема только в том, что в конце списка остается лишняя запятая.

Comment: О, а если вот так без цикла `labels: [@Html.Raw(string.Join(", ", Model.Select(x => string.Join(", ", x.NameArea.Select(y => "'" + y + "'")))))]`?

Comment: Я еще разбираюсь со своим форматированием. И возможно моя проблема в том, что я не правильно использую метод Join. И Json я не разбирал, хотелось бы избежать его на этот раз.

Comment: Быть может не заметили мой предыдущий комментарий, посмотрите, должно с запятыми помочь.

Comment: Он разделяет но посимвольно, а не по элементам.

Comment: Тогда может так? `labels: [@Html.Raw(string.Join(", ", Model.Select(x => "'" +  x.NameArea + "'")))]`

Comment: Получилось реализовать?